# Autovote up on answering accept

Tags: feature-request, new-users, up-votes

I have a suggestion.

Not a reputation whore, but I have seen that some users accept an answer but not upvoting it. Two examples that recently happened to me are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806708/how-to-design-a-school-billing-system-database-schema/15807019#15807019) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874965/unit-test-in-c-sharp-with-jenkins/15875181#15875181). The way I see it is that when I accept an answer I upvote it.

As you can see users are new to Stack Overflow (reputation very low) and probably don't know how it works.

My suggestion is find a way of improving this by:

- Putting a message on question acceptance.
- Auto voting up accepted answer if user is pretty new (reputation under 100 or similar)

Against it I am not sure on the % of accepted answers without votes so not sure if this is needed or not...

Comment: I'm trying to think of a situation where you wouldn't want to upvote an answer you're accepting, but I can't think of any time that could occur, so I think this is a smart idea.

Comment: Please don't. Otherwise no one can earn [Tenacious](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/225/tenacious) and [Unsung Hero](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero) badges.

Comment: @cad - Note that you have tagged this question with feature-request. So no need to add suggestion in the title. :)

Comment: I didn't knew. Thanks :)

Comment: Answers just giving direct and short answer (e.g. fix `veriable` to `variable`) doesn't really deserve upvotes. True enough it solved the problem but it's far from being outstanding answer. Don't decide for the OP how to act, it's their full right to even downvote plus accept.

Answer (score 10):

The latter user has 10 reputation. The right to upvote is earned at 15 reputation.

See https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Therefore, this proposal doesn't make a lot of sense for the type of users you're talking about.

Comment: I didn't realize this. Anyways is weird accepting an answer and not having power to upvote it...

Comment: I'd then suggest that we should maybe lower the limit of upvoting for answers to your own question? E.g. normally it's 15 rep. but for answers to your own question it is 10?

Comment: In hindsight, there is probably a reason for the limit on accepting answers (though I'm curious as to what it is); so my assumption that one should reign supreme on their own questions is probably invalid.

Comment: @VonLion the reasoning, I believe, is to make it more difficult for people to create new (sock-puppet) accounts for the purposes of upvoting your own posts.